# Testing Behavior equality in Akka Typed

Tags: akka, akka-typed

In a test I want to assert that a certain (parameterized) Behavior is returned by a kind of factory method. How can I do that?

```
def myBehavior(param: Int) = Behaviors.receiveMessage { ... }
```

When I call `myBehavior` twice, I get two different objects (which is what I would expect) but they are not equal.

I thought about making a case class that extends `ExtensibleBehavior`. However, I don't know how to delegate to a behavior defined using the `Behaviors` DSL. Apart from that I don't like the indirection that is introduced by the additional class.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: I've struggled with the same thing. From a purity perspective, it's beautiful that Behavior is just a function from T -> Behavior[T], but testing state transitions (or lack thereof) purely on external effects is often a challenge, especially since the behavior isn't a class that you could extend in testing with a new message that lets you extract the state (for example)

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. I've read the documentation and looked at the source code and I can't find anything useful. You would have thought that there would have been a way of testing behavior transitions.

Comment: I've posted a solution in a lightbend akka forum https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/not-sure-how-to-test-behaviors-in-akka-typed/4747 . It is not elegant but will allow you to test behavior by using context.log and then looking at the logs using testkit.logEntries in your tests

Comment: @AbdulJabbarAzam Thanks, but what I need is a bit different. I am not executing the behavior. I just want to assert that a certain behavior is returned by a factory given a specific set of parameters.